# Arduino struct with pointer to itself leaks memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, struct, arduino

I have an arduino program where I want to store data in a **dynamic list**. For this I use the following `struct`:

```
struct Project {
  boolean         status;
  String          name;
  struct Project* nextProject;
};
```

Now I generate a dynamic amount of `Project` objects, depending on extern data. I only have the first `Project` object as variable, the rest i can get through the `nextProject` pointer.

The generation of the `Project` objects is done in my `loop` again every minute. The problem is that from time to time I loos memory till it's empty.
This is how my main loop looks like:

```
void loop() {
  webServer(server);
  webClient();

  if (parseTimer(60)) {
    sendRequest();
  }
}
```

(`parseTimer` is a non blocking delay function that returns `true` every 60 seconds; `sendRequest` generates the `Project` objects)

My method to measure the memory:

```
uint8_t* stackptr;
uint8_t* heapptr;

long getFreeMemory() {
  stackptr = (uint8_t *) malloc(4);
  heapptr  = stackptr;
  free(stackptr);
  stackptr = (uint8_t *) (SP);

  return long(stackptr) - long(heapptr);
}
```

This is the ammount of memory each loop:

```
1:  4716 *
2:  4716 *
3:  4716 *
4:  4671
5:  4687
6:  4587 *
7:  4736
8:  4587 *
9:  4559
10: 4577
11: 4515
12: 4527
13: 4587 *
14: 4479
15: 4497
16: 4435
17: 4447
18: 4587 *
19: 4399
20: 4417
21: 4355
22: 4367
23: 4587 *
24: 4319
```

Memory is getting less but after the first few loops, every 5th loop I have `4587 Bytes` of free memory. After ~280 loops the program is out of memory, but till there every 5th loop has exactly `4587 Bytes` free memory.
Can anyone explain me what could be the cause for this strange behavior and how can I create a better dynamic list that doesn't leaks memory.

**UPDATE**

In each loop the `Project` objects are generated, used and deleted. It does sth. like this:

```
void sendRequest() {
  // at first it gets some remote data from a server the result is:
  String  names[]  = {"Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3"};
  boolean states[] = {true, false, true};

  for(int i = 0; i <= projectCount; i++) {
    addProject(names[i], states[i]);
  }
}

// all variables that are not declarated here are declarated in the
// header file of the class
void addProject(String name, boolean state) {
  if (!startProject) {
    startProject = true;

    firstProject.status      = state;
    firstProject.name        = name;
    firstProject.nextProject = NULL;

    ptrToLastProject = &firstProject;
  } else {
    ptrToLastProject->nextProject = new Project();

    ptrToLastProject->nextProject->status      = tempProjectStatus;
    ptrToLastProject->nextProject->name        = tempData;
    ptrToLastProject->nextProject->nextProject = NULL;

    ptrToLastProject = ptrToLastProject->nextProject;
  }
}

void RssParser::resetParser() { 
  delete ptrToLastProject;
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Are you creating new Project objects in every loop iteration? If so, it's normal that your memory usage increases and it does not mean that you are leaking memory.

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for you `Project` structures?

Comment: You need to show more code, there's absolutely nothing that indicates that the linked list in itself is the problem (the declaration is fine).

Comment: I know nothing about arduino development. Why aren't you using a `std::list`?

Comment: Added some code that shows how I generate the "List" @Dave sry but I can't use std functions.

Comment: There is no std in arduino, I could load it via an external library but this takes too much flash and sram.

Comment: Where are the `Project` objects being deleted?

Comment: Please simplify the code as much as possible and post it all.  You should be able to take out all the networking and just debug using the UART.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research and writing unit tests for nearly every function of the project I was able to find the mistake.

In my `resetParser()` function i did only a `delete ptrToLastProject`. But there was an other Pointer to this object so the memory was not released. Adding this to the `resetParser()` function fixed the leak.

```
delete firstProject.nextProject;
```

The reason for this is because the `firstProject` is on the stack with an pointer to the other projects in the list on the heap. When I delete this pointer all other objects in the list are deleted too by their destructors.

Comment: 1. You can have multiple pointers to the same memory, deleting only one pointer will free the memory, leaving the rest dangling. 2. If you delete a `Project` object that holds a pointer to another heap allocated `Project` object, this will **NOT** destruct the second object, you must explicitly call `delete` on all `new`'d memory.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're not leaking memory because on every 5th iteration your memory is back to **4587 bytes**

There is however, an interesting pattern occurring here. You'll notice that each *set of calls* to `getFreeMemory` that occurs *before* you have **4587 bytes** is always **80 bytes** less than the last set.

I'm going to *guesstimate* that there is more and more data being received on each `sendRequest`, and in return, you're attempting to **allocate more memory** each run through the loop. It's all well and good that you're releasing it somewhere, but at some point you're trying to allocate too much!

One possibility is that you're **appending** the request data, rather than overwriting it, and subsequently the `projectCount` is constantly increased.

As a side-note, be careful of **this**:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= projectCount; i++) {
    addProject(names[i], states[i]);
}
```

Looping through arrays requires a **0 based index**. When you check the condition `i <= projectCount` you may be overrunning your buffer. If there are `3` elements in `names`, and your `projectCount` is `3`, what happens when `i = 3` and you access `names[i]`?